# Linux cron job overwrite file

Tags: linux, file, cron

In case of cron job that creates an archive with a constant name will the archive be replaced with new one on the next cron job or terminated as the file with this name is already exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no magic in `cron` - it just runs a program at a given timing. If that program has the logic to check if the archive exists, it will still have it when run via as a cron job. If it just overwrites the archive, it will continue doing so when run as a cron jbo.

Answer (score 1):

Cron just run your command, so it's up to you how this command may look. For example:

```
0 8 * * * rm -rf arc.zip && zip -r arc.zip /tmp
```

This cron runs every day at 8am and performs next steps:

1. remove file `arc.zip`
2. create new archive `arc.zip` from `/tmp`
   directory